# My project is expecting a dll in the bin but it can't find it

Tags: .net, .net-2.0, activereports

I have copied a project from my old XP machine to my new Win7 machine. It's a console app targeting the .net 2.0 framework. It uses a reporting tool called Active Reports. Active Reports has a series of dlls in the Program Files directory that are referenced in the project. When the project is run I get the error

```
Could not load file or assembly 'file:///C:\PROJECTPATH\bin\Debug\ActiveReports.Interop.Dll' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
```

There is no need for this dll to be in the bin and when I copy it there the project doesn't even build.

Why is VS expecting the dll to be in the bin?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the build of Active Reports I was using (4.2.1.1238) wasn't compatible with Win7. I re-installed Active Reports with a newer build (4.2.1.1261) and I'm no longer getting the error.

Answer (score 1):

Check if there is a warning on the reference to the Active Report DLL in your project references. The path might not be the same on your win7 machine as on your XP machine.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. No warnings. I've removed the references and added them again and I'm still getting the same error.

Comment: [This page](http://www.datadynamics.com/Forums/72/ShowForum.aspx) has a number of downloads for your referenced dll. Presumably there are instructions for installing them, and the installation performs whatever registry tweaks are needed for the DLL to work properly. Consider downloading the relevant one and installing it.  If that doesn't work, search your code for the assembly name; sometimes unit tests like to add a [ReferencedAssembly] attribute to the methods (or something like it); this attribute can be safely removed if you didn't put it there.

Comment: Reinstalled Active Reports using a newer build and the project now runs. I guess the old build is only compatible with XP. Thanks for your help!